# Qual a melhor forma de fazer um backup de banco de dados online

Tags: c#, mysql, backup

Existe uma cliente minha que possui duas máquinas, uma delas é o servidor aonde ficam todos os dados do banco, e o outro é o caixa.

Porém, existe a preocupação da cliente de caso algo aconteça com o servidor os dados ficarem salvos em algum lugar na internet. Portanto, eu via C# (que é feita a aplicação do caixa) gero um arquivo ".sql" todas as noites com o backup de todos os dados do banco. E envio esse ".sql" via FTP pra um servidor meu.

A minha grande dúvida é se o método que estou utilizando é bom, por que notamos que quanto mais tempo passa, maior o arquivo ".sql" vai ficando e mais tempo se leva para enviar o arquivo para o servidor FTP. Gostaria de saber se o método utilizado é bom e viável ou se existe algo melhor.

Comment: Pesquise por "redo log", que é basicamente um arquivo que só cresce e nunca é modificado. Este arquivo pode ser copiado "a quente", usando alguma ferramenta tão simples como rsync. Já os arquivos do banco nunca devem ser copiados a quente (acho que o Oracle recusa-se a abrir um banco copiado assim) porque o arquivo certamente vai estar corrrompido e é modificado em todas as partes, complicando a vida de um rsync da vida.

Comment: Se o banco for MySQL, eis algumas informações sobre "redo log" do InnoDB: https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/redo_logging_in_innodb

Answer (score 4):

O problema é de banda/tamanho de arquivo.

Não sei se o mysql consegue fazer backup differencial. Se fosse um MS SQL ou Oracle eu faria um backup diferencial por dia e um full por semana (provavelmente, mas isso depende de cada cenário).
De qualquer forma vc está perguntando apenas pela mídia (salvar na nuvem, disco, fita, internet, etc) e não vai ter muita diferença entre uma e outra além desses tempos de upload/download etc.

Eu diria que seu método é bom para bases pequenas e muita banda. Mas também você deve verificar o tempo que vc vai demorar para restaurar essa base fazendo donwload do seu ftp server.

Lembre-se o backup é apenas um dos requisitos para permitir uma restauração do sistema. Verifique se vc tem um plano de contigência para essas ocorrências e quanto isso vai demorar (e se vai de fato mitigar a situação).

Voltando ao x da questão. Verifique a possibilidade de backups diferenciais ou se há outro server disponível para ser o storage desses arquivos.
Quando trabalhava de DBA "acidental" tinhamos uma fita para cada dia da semana e tiravamos vários backups diferenciais e um full a cada dia enquanto as outras seis fitas ficavam num cofre.

Comment: Para complementar o que o @jean disse, será que você não pode se "livrar de algumas tabelas, ou de alguns registros ?" por exemplo logs, excluir os de muito tempo atrás? E esse arquivo ele cresce em um ritmo absurdamente grande?? Se você acha que ele cresce em um ritmo acelerado e muito grande você poderia começar a pensar em outras alternativas de base de dados, um No-SQL da vida por exemplo. Mas se essa mudança se torna inviável, você pode pensar em utilizar a [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replic

Comment: Não cresce em ritmo absurdo, mas o problema é a fraca conexão do lugar. O banco agora está com 2 megas, e lá demora cerca de uns 10 minutos pra enviar pro servidor (Fiz teste no meu computador, na minha conexão e leva só 1 minuto). Os backups diferenciais não dão muito trabalho? Por exemplo, se após uns 2 anos der problema no servidor eu não teria que pegar TODOS os scripts e executar todos em ordem?

Comment: 2 megas é uma base minúscula. Você pode encher um DVD regravável com montes desses backups. Não o backup diferencial é ~"oquê aconteceu desde o último full backup". Dai você restaura o último full e os diferenciais, em ordem que ocorreram, depois. Por isto ainda é necessário backups full.

Comment: No seu caso até um pendrive de 1 GB vai ser um storage, consiga 7 pen drives baratos e use um por semana como storage lembrando de trocar todo dia e guardando os seis num local físicamente separado do server você não terá problemas